# Exponential analogue of NC?

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, parallel-computing, complexity-classes

[Nick's Class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_(complexity)) (NC) is the class of problems that can be decided in poly-log time using a polynomial number of processors.

I want to know about the exponential analogue, which would cover problems that can be decided in polynomial time using an exponential number of processors.

What I'm looking for is a name for this class and any known relations between this class and other complexity classes, or any canonical problems for the class. It seems straightforward that it would contain NP and co-NP, and i think it is contained within PSPACE, but I'm not sure much else about it.

Comment: I wrote up an answer, but then found it answered here: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6753/what-is-the-big-version-of-nc

Answer (score 1):

Time in circuits corresponds to the depth.
Therefore by polynomial time means polynomial depth.

The number of processors is the size of the circuit, 
i.e. number of the gates in the circuit.
So by exponential number of processors you allow exponential size.
This would be the class $\mathsf{DepthSize}(n^{O(1)}, 2^{n^{O(1)}})$.
But *every* function is already in $\mathsf{DepthSize}(2, 2^{n^{O(1)}})$
(think of the CNF of the function you want to compute).

The take away is that exponential number of processors is 
too strong to be useful by itself.

One reasonable restriction to put is to limit the amount of communication
between different processes.
E.g. we each process can only communicate with 
only polynomially many other processes and the messages have polynomial size.
That would be $\mathsf{PSpace}$ as explained in answers to [Aterm's question on cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/6753/).
Another way to see it to remember that 
$\mathsf{PSpace} = \mathsf{ATime}(n^{O(1)})$,
problems computable by alternating Turing machines in polynomial time.
Alternation in Turing machines is essentially forking new processes and then joining after they finish by taking the conjunction/disjunction of their return values.

Comment: One gets PSPACE even when the only restriction on communication is the time bound. ​ ​

Comment: @Ricky, it really depends on the model. If the model is alternating Turing machine then yes as I have written in my answer. If it is general circuits (the nonuniform NC circuits) then not so. The time bound for circuits is depth and any function is computable by a depth 2 CNF.

Comment: The OP specified the model as parallel machine. ​ ​

Comment: @Ricky, what do you mean by "parallel machine"? There is many models that try to capture the notion of parallel computation. E.g. take [PRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_random-access_machine). OP asks about NC which is a class of circuits and w.r.t. that what I stated holds.

Comment: I essentially mean PRAM. ​ The OP says NC "is the class of problems that can be decided in poly-log time using a polynomial number of processors", and asks about "problems that can be decided in polynomial time using an exponential number of processors." ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @Ricky, Sorry, but I don't see your point.

Comment: I was just looking some descriptive complexity notes and noticed that $\mathsf{PSpace} = \mathsf{FO}[2^{n^{O(1)}}] = \mathsf{CRAM}[2^{n^{O(1)}}]$. However it seems it is essential for $\mathsf{FO}[2^{n^{O(1)}}] = \mathsf{PSpace}$ that we have fixed number of variables that does not grow with $n$.